# Get Pixels of SubImage

Tags: java, image-processing, clojure, io, interop

Consider the following simple Clojure to Java interop for reading the pixel data of images:

```clj
(import java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
(import javax.imageio.ImageIO)
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn read-image [path]
  (ImageIO/read (io/file path)))

(defn get-sub-image [img x y w h]
  (.getSubimage img x y w h))

;; this assumes that images have no fourth alpha channel:
(defn get-pixels
  ([img x y w h] (get-pixels (get-sub-image img x y w h)))
  ([img] (let [bytes (-> img .getRaster .getDataBuffer .getData)]
           (map vec (partition 3 bytes)))))
```

This works fine for getting pixels of the whole image, like so:

```clj
(def all-pixels (get-pixels (read-image "path/to/img.jpg")))
(nth all-pixels 0)
;; [34 56 7]
(count all-pixels)
;; 122343
```

However, when trying to call get-pixels with the additional coordinate arguments, the result still contains the whole data:

```clj
(def some-pixels (get-pixels (read-image "path/to/img.jpg") 0 0 2 2))
(count some-pixels)
;; 122343
```

Here I'd rather expect to receive only 4 pixels. Where's the flaw?

Also any comments on the general approach of processing image data as lazy sequences are welcome.

Comment: From the doc of `getSubImage`:  `The returned BufferedImage shares the same data array as the original image.` Isn't that a reason? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to read the code but if we walk trough source code :

```
    public BufferedImage More ...getSubimage (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        return new BufferedImage (colorModel,
                                  raster.createWritableChild(x, y, w, h,
                                                             0, 0, null),
                                  colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(),
                                  properties);
   }
```

This method calls `raster.createWritableChild`
Let's see...

```
 public WritableRaster More ...createWritableChild(int parentX, int parentY,
                                              int w, int h,
                                             int childMinX, int childMinY,
                                             int bandList[]) {
        if (parentX < this.minX) {
            throw new RasterFormatException("parentX lies outside raster");
        }
        if (parentY < this.minY) {
            throw new RasterFormatException("parentY lies outside raster");
        }
        if ((parentX+w < parentX) || (parentX+w > this.width + this.minX)) {
            throw new RasterFormatException("(parentX + width) is outside raster");
        }
        if ((parentY+h < parentY) || (parentY+h > this.height + this.minY)) {
            throw new RasterFormatException("(parentY + height) is outside raster");
        }

        SampleModel sm;
        // Note: the SampleModel for the child Raster should have the same
        // width and height as that for the parent, since it represents
        // the physical layout of the pixel data.  The child Raster's width
        // and height represent a "virtual" view of the pixel data, so
        // they may be different than those of the SampleModel.
        if (bandList != null) {
            sm = sampleModel.createSubsetSampleModel(bandList);
        }
        else {
            sm = sampleModel;
        }

        int deltaX = childMinX - parentX;
        int deltaY = childMinY - parentY;

        return new WritableRaster(sm,
                                  getDataBuffer(),
                                  new Rectangle(childMinX,childMinY,
                                                w, h),
                                  new Point(sampleModelTranslateX+deltaX,
                                            sampleModelTranslateY+deltaY),
                                 this);
    }
```

As you can see, the new raster created has the same DataBuffer than its parent (probably to allow modification of the whole image if you update the sub-image) so when you do

```
img .getRaster .getDataBuffer
```

You get the databuffer of the whole image.

I did not test of course but `BufferedImage.getData(Rectangle rect)` should return a new raster with its own DataBuffer and then do as you did

See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.java#BufferedImage.getData%28%29

**EDIT : Anton Harald's (op) final tested answer**

```
(defn get-data [img x y w h] 
  (-> (.getData img (Rectangle. x y w h)) 
      .getDataBuffer 
      .getData))
```

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. Especially because it points out the different meaning of a subimage. If you want, you can add this to your answer: (defn get-data [img x y w h] (-> (.getData img (Rectangle. x y w h)) .getDataBuffer .getData))  This is the approach I finally used, derived from your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i added your answer